# search function in simple todo list javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm trying to make TodoList with search filter, to show searched task and display only this one task. I cant do this. Is a problem with function `searchTask`. I cant hide other tasks and show searched one. ;(

Thanks for help.

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const addBtn = document.querySelector('addButton');
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const listItems = document.getElementsByClassName('task');
const inputSearch = document.querySelector("input.search");

function removeTask(e) {
    const item = e.target;
    if (item.classList[0] === 'trash-btn') {
        const todo = item.parentElement;
        todo.classList.add('fall');
        todo.addEventListener("transitionend", function () {
            todo.remove();
        })
    }
    // e.target.parentNode.remove();
}

function addTask(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const titleTask = input.value;
    if (titleTask === "") return;
    const task = document.createElement('li');
    task.className = 'task';
    task.innerHTML = titleTask;
    ul.appendChild(task);
    const trashButton = document.createElement('button');
    trashButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>';
    trashButton.classList.add("trash-btn");
    task.appendChild(trashButton);
    input.value = "";
    task.querySelector('.trash-btn').addEventListener('click', removeTask)
}

const searchTask = (e) => {
    const searchText = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    let tasks = [...listItems];
    if (tasks.filter(li => li.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText)) != -1) {
        tasks.forEach(li => li.style.display = "flex");
    } else {
        tasks.forEach(li => li.style.display = "none");
    }
}

form.addEventListener('submit', addTask);
inputSearch.addEventListener('input', searchTask);
```

Comment: Can you describe what is not working correctly?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: there is no error but everything disappears after type text in searchbox and i dont know why. I just staretd learn js and i cant find solution.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.filter()` does not modify the array. You need to store the results that it is producing, or else your `tasks` array will just be `listItems`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const searchTask = (e) => {
    let tasks = [...listItems];
    searchText = inputSearch.value.toLowerCase();
    if (searchText === "") {
        tasks.forEach(item => item.style.display = "flex");
    } else {
        tasks.forEach(item => item.style.display = "none");
        tasks.filter(item => item.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)).forEach(item => item.style.display = "flex");
    }
}
```

i rebuilded searchTask function like this and now its fine :D